# feathersJS custom authentication

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

im trying to create an auth with feathersJS.  im not there when they did it from the beginning they create the services MANUALLY, meaning they did not use the  command "feathers generate service", now, everything works fine. but now they want me to implment a authentication to their login, i saw some example in documentation that i have to put in default.json like this

```
"authentication": {
"entity": null,
"service": "users",
"secret": "fhaCVRbeGa0XDMcxRKcnTMz/Ti8=",
"authStrategies": [
  "jwt",
  "local"
],
"jwtOptions": {
  "header": {
    "typ": "access"
  },
  "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
  "issuer": "feathers",
  "algorithm": "HS256",
  "expiresIn": "1d"
},
"local": {
  "usernameField": "userName",
  "passwordField": "password"
}
```

}

so my first question is this. where should i get that entity? is that as is for name? or there must be a file that exist for that?
thanks

Comment: and on  my second question, how do I point my authentication like when i load the request body with this
{
    "strategy": "local",
    "userName": "my_us",
    "password": "my_pw"
}
it will find in a specific table. like it will point on our users table named system_users

Comment: `entity` is almost always 'user' and is what the thing returned to an authenticated client that has the user info. `service` is a feathers service (using feathers-mongoose, feathers-sequelize, etc. or a custom one that implements the common interface https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html - this would likely be a service closely related to `system_users`

Comment: What are you using as services that talk to your data store?

Comment: hello all, thanks for the help, I already solved it using your help and i noticed also i havent included .hooks file, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help, I already solved it using your help and i noticed also i havent included .hooks file, thanks
something like this

```js
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    get: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    create: [ hashPassword('password') ],
    update: [ hashPassword('password'),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    patch: [ hashPassword('password'),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    remove: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
  },
```